# Gtk Widget for Suggestion

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Which gtk widget should I use for achieving this functionality:

[image: Auto Suggestion while typing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GtkEntryCompletion](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryCompletion.html). Run `gtk-demo` to see how it behaves.